# Adding an internal web application to Google Apps

Tags: google-apps

I have just re-written the authentication for one of our internal web applications to rely on Google Apps federated login with OpenID and it works nicely. However, to be a totally perfect solution, I wonder if it is possible to add the internal application to the More link on Google Apps top bar where you would see Google Apps marketplace applications listed?

I thought perhaps the only way to do this would be to deploy on App Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a listing in the [Google Apps market](https://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/?pli=1) place. You do not have to make your listing public, you can keep it private for use within your company and still deploy it onto your GAPPS for Business.

When deploying in the marketplace, you have to provide a [manifest file](http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/manifest.html), which defines the 'More link'. Google calls this the Universal navigation.
Basically, something like this is needed in the manifest :

```
  <!-- Show this link in Google's universal navigation for all users -->
  <Extension id="navLink" type="link">
    <Name>AppTest</Name>
    <Url>http://www.example.com/home.php?from=google&amp;domain=${DOMAIN_NAME}</Url>
    <!-- This app also uses the Calendar API -->
    <Scope ref="calendarFeed"/>
  </Extension>
```